# Multiple WSO2 ESB nodes clustered without Greg

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, esb, wso2-governance-registry

Is it possible that 2 WSO2 ESB nodes points to external datastore and sharing deployed artifacts without having WSO2 GReg product in place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a clustered setup, you can mount your registry artifacts to an external datastore and access them from 2 WSO2 ESBs or more. Hope this guide will help you to achieve this.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Remote+Registry+Instance+Configuration